What's the meaning of "he can score" here?
From the the novel "Fat City":

“That’s right, sure, they won’t go for just anybody.”
“If the right guy comes along he can score.”
“Everybody’s got a mate somewhere.”


Merriam-Webster: 3b: to be successful. Meaning he is picky about who he dates.

What's the source? What's the context?

@WeatherVane thank you so much. Wouldn't it mean to have intercourse with her?

@Laurel from the the novel " Fat City "

Often, it does mean that. Or it could be more general. As in "I was a hit" – "I made a score / mark".

@WeatherVane thank you.

'He can score' here means 'he can persuade a woman to have sex with him'. The (fairly big) clues are in the text preceding and following that which you posted.

Gene Simms was working nights at the box factory, and the two began
passing afternoons together. Driving his car or riding in Ernie’s,
haggard, frowning, yawning, smoking with yellowed unsteady fingers, a
blond oily lock hanging over his forehead, Gene talked mostly on the
same subject, his descriptive powers arousing in Ernie a curious
agitation and a fear that what he had with Faye might be of a quality
below the possible or even the usual.   “Well, I don’t know.”
“But you got to know what you’re doing.”
“That’s right, sure, they won’t go for just anybody.”
“If the right guy comes along he can score.”
“There isn’t a one that don’t want it,” said Gene.
“Everybody’s got a mate somewhere.”
“I don’t care who it is. You know Eleanor MacDonald? I plugged her.”
“I know, you told me.”
“You got to understand their minds. If you can get your knee between
their legs you’re usually on your way.”

From 'Fat City' by Leonard Gardner
The subject is sex, and how to persuade women to let a man have it with them (success at this is one meaning of 'scoring'). 'Plugging' is a crude and vulgar way of referring to the sex act, and this points to the type of person Gene is, and his attitude towards women. This and the language that Gardner uses when describing him ('oily lock', 'yellowed unsteady finger') paints a picture of a sordid and unsavoury character.

Score (verb) [ Intransitive ] slang
to have sex with someone that you have usually just met:
Did you score last night, then?

Score (verb) - Cambridge Dictionary

Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. Excuse me, I have another question. I hope I don't seem rude. At the following dialogue, why did Gene say, " I don't care who it is?" Why "it" not " she"? Would it imply that he doesn't care about gender of the person whom he wants to have intercourse with.

@SoroushGh given Gene's disposition as outlined in this answer, perhaps so, and it suggests he cares little about any human qualities. Contrast this with Ernie's “If the right guy comes along he can score,” and “Everybody’s got a mate somewhere,” and Ernie's fear that what he has with Faye may be too carnal for his liking.

@WeatherVane thank you so much.

@WeatherVane excuse me. About your last sentence, could you explain more? Because I think it means he was shocked about his physical relationship with his wife when he heard Gene description. What he has heard about that subject we don't know, but what the narrator says makes us think that Ernie now thinks the number of lovemaking with his wife is few.

@SoroushGh - we can use 'it' about people when we don't know, care, or mind who they are. Who is it at the door? There will be a new manager next week, but I don't know who it will be. There is no automatic implication of indifference about gender; it's just more compact than saying or writing 'he or she'. These days we might use 'they'. Gene could, perhaps, equally well have said 'she' (he claims to be a voracious 'plugger' of women) , but using 'it' is appropriate, given his uncaring nature, as Weather Vane says. Also Gene is a worker in a box factory, not an English scholar.

@SoroushGh - It seems to me that Ernie fears that his own sex life life seems rather domesticated, 'tame', or dull by comparison with the picture painted by Gene of his. Ernie and Gene seem, respectively, to be naive and boastful. It is by no means certain that Gene has as much sex as he claims to.

@MichaelHarvey I really appreciate your help.

@SoroushGh sorry I didn't realise they were married.

@WeatherVane your explanation was helpful, thanks.
